# How to determine the ranges when fitting piecewise equation?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am currently giving a fitting equation in matlab for a scatter plot like this:

[image: ScatterPlot]

It seems that we'd better make it a piecewise equation

But how should I determine the ranges of those segmented funtions? Is there an api in matlab for this?

Comment: Don't know about matlab, but if possible I'd fit x(y) rather than y(x), on that data Otherwise you could place the split point as parameter in a least square. In this particular case, however it wouldn't help very much either---at least in y(x)---as points belonging to the middle part are left of where the first graph ends. Here an [EMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) may help.

Comment: It looks to me as if there are two different "Y" values at X = 5.5 on the scatterplot red lines. If you post a link to the data, I will run it through my zunzun.com web site's "function finder" and try to find a single equation.